# Secure login for Firefox alternatives

Tags: firefox

For some reason, Secure Login 0.9.3. on FF 3.5.4. is relatively buggy (it randomly stops working saying it is not compatible, but continues to work after I uninstall it and reinstall afterwards ... then it stops working after some time. No new extensions were added in the meantime; just BitDefender was installed on the system ... not sure whether he has something to do with it.).

What would be good alternatives to it (except RoboForm) which give the same behaviour ?

All ideas welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

[Lastpass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8542) does the job for me. Been using it for over a year now with absolutely no problems.

Comment: I've tried it. But Lastpass is not an alternative for SL; it stores your data online, which is quite a difference.